# Scala: posting JSON to local HTML

Tags: javascript, json, scala, http, post

EDIT: I stored the HTML page on a web server..
I would like to send a JSON to an HTML stored on a web server.

I'm using the scalaj-http library (https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http)

But I can't achieve this .

Here is my scala code:

```
import scalaj.http.{Http, HttpOptions}

object PostObj {
  val result = Http("http:\\mywebserver\\page.html").postData("\"{\"id\":\"12\",\"json\":\"data\"}\"")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .header("Charset", "UTF-8")
    .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(10000)).asString
}
```

While, the HTML page is written in Javascript.
How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for who will help me! :)

Comment: you don't post to a HTML page, you usually post to a web server or API endpoint. I don't understand what you like to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I was looking for a way to send a JSON to a local HTML to make quickly and easy tests (without using a web server or anything else). Is this not possible in any way (even by changing the POST method)?

Comment: now I put my HTML page on a web server.

Comment: You *cannot* post to an HTML page. It doesn't matter where you put it. The two things simply have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with each other. You post to an HTTP server which understands the POST method.

Comment: Maybe what you meant to do was request the data from your javascript on the HTML page, with an ajax request? the other way around